# Can I access Android HCE application if device is turned off?

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I'm currently write Android HCE application. And I want to use my HCE application when the device is turned off. I found a way to "[Access HCE when Screen off](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil17X_n4fTAhUCW5QKHZ4RAuYQygQIJDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fconnectivity%2Fnfc%2Fhce.html%23ScreenOffBehavior&usg=AFQjCNHKCL7h7xqSdizIVPMpukW7l7267A&sig2=paBrmQal9ASar7umi34dYQ&bvm=bv.151325232,d.dGo)", but no information of power off status.

Is there any way to use HCE application when phone is turned off?

Comment: How is an application supposed to run if the phone is turned off? Of course it can't work. When doing anything with HCE you always need your emulation service which requires your phone to be on. While the NFC chip could technically still be used when phone is off, all the software behind it required for HCE is not available.

Comment: Thanks. I understand HCE requires phone's CPU.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you can't access because of security reason 
One correction also its not accessible if screen is off as mentioned in provided link.

Current Android implementations turn the NFC controller and the application processor off completely when the screen of the device is turned off. HCE services will therefore not work when the screen is off.

It may work on some devices only if vendor implements the OS customized.